# Getting video stream from an IP camera to android smart phone

Tags: android, webcam

I would like to send the video from axis M1011 - W Network camera to the android phone. Using the rstp protocoll, with the following command: 
rtsp://192.168.1.17/mpeg4/media.amp?videocodec=h264
I am able to reproduce the video over mobile.
Howewer, i have about 4 sec of delay. I want to reduce the delay. How can i set the buffer size in order to reduce the delay?

Thanks

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm trying to do the same, it would be great if you could share some info with me?

Comment: @User422688 I know this post is too old. But I am looking for such a thing for 3 days. can you tell me how can I see the video on my android device from an IP camera?